# Dynamically typed associations with STI models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, single-table-inheritance, belongs-to

I have a parent model *Account* with multiple subclasses using STI. I want to associate another model *Transaction* using a belongs_to relationship to *Account*. The referenced account could be either an *Asset* or a *Liability*.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base end
class Asset < Account end
class Liability < Account end
```

My transaction model belongs_to *Account*

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account #Either an Asset or Liability model
end
```

I want to be able to set a transaction's account to either an Asset or a Liability. However, I get a TypeMismatch error when I set the transaction's account to an Asset or Liablity since it isn't the parent class *Account*.

Note: I think this could be solved using polymorphism on the belongs_to association, but it seems unnecessary to specify the class in a type column when the referenced models all use the same underlying table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this code works as is. You don't need to specify a polymorphic type on the associated model to the STI model.

The type mismatch error I was receiving was because my STI base class was actually "Account::Base" and I simply had "Account" as the class name.